# HTML tables and Page Header/Footer overlap

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation, css-tables

I have been trying to generate a PDF from an HTML file, and require the generated PDF to have a page header and a page footer. They must be printed on every page. While using 'static' for position, I do get the page headers/footers to be printed on every page generated. But, when I add a table to my HTML, I notice that the table shows above the footer on the first page, and the page header does not print on the second page. I need the table to adjust itself to above the footer, and any extra rows to be shown in the next page, after the page footer.

Here is the skeleton of my code, with appropriate formats that I need, FYI, the report header and footer are generated only once per document, and that works just fine.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Invoice</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      }

      .container {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
      }

      .page-header,
      .page-header-space,
      .page-footer,
      .page-footer-space {
        height: 100px;
      }

      .invoice-details {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      .invoice-details p {
        margin: 0;
      }

      .table-container {
        page-break-inside: always;
      }

      .table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        max-height: 400px;
        /* or set a fixed height */
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .table th,
      .table td {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .table th {
        background-color: #999999;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .table tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #d3d3d3;
      }

      .table tr:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
      }

      .total-container {
        background-color: #444;
        display: inline-block;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 60%;
      }

      .total {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        margin-top: 5px;
      }

      .total p {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 10px;
      }

      .report-header {
        display: block;
        justify-content: flex-center;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
      }

      .report-header h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .report-header h2 {
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .report-header h3 {
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .report-footer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 30px;
      }

      .report-footer p {
        margin: 0;
      }

      .page-header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: block;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
      }

      .page-header h2 {
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .page-header p {
        margin: 20px;
      }

      .page-footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: block;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      .page-footer p {
        margin: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="report-header">
        <h1>Company Primary Name</h1>
        <h2>Company Address Line 1</h2>
        <h2>Company Address Line 2</h2>
        <h2>Company Address Line 3</h2>
        <h2>Company Phone Number</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h2>Tax Invoice</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="invoice-details">
        <p>Invoice Date: May 1, 2023</p>
        <p>Due Date: May 31, 2023</p>
      </div>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <div class="header-space">&nbsp;</div>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>$10.00</td>
            <td>$20.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>$20.00</td>
            <td>$20.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>$5.00</td>
            <td>$15.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>$5.00</td>
            <td>$15.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>$5.00</td>
            <td>$15.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>$5.00</td>
            <td>$15.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>$5.00</td>
            <td>$15.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>$5.00</td>
            <td>$15.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>$5.00</td>
            <td>$15.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>$5.00</td>
            <td>$15.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>$5.00</td>
            <td>$15.00</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="total-container">
        <div class="total">
          <p>Grand Total:</p>
          <p>$100.00</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="page-footer">
        <p>Page Footer Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="report-footer">
        <p>Company Email</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

this blog entry may help you as it did me:
https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a

**edit**

I assume you stumbled on this already, because your class names look similar. you need to adapt your skeleton with a table that uses the `page-header-space` in the `<thead>` and the `page-footer-space` class in the `<tfoot>`

the result should look something like this:

```
<body>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="page-header-space">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="content ">

                    <!-- your content -->

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="page-footer-space">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<div class="page-header">

    <!-- your header html -->

</div>
<div class="page-footer">

    <!-- your footer html -->

</div>
```

this is your "skeleton-table" for printing.
you have to put your "data-table" into the content-div. remove the `<div class="header-space">&nbsp;</div>` from it.

Comment: I was able to make all changes required, with the help of your suggestion! Made one tiny edit though, I changed the <td style="border:none;> right before the footer-space and the header space, which actually was creating a border for that 'column' per se.